# Excel VBA - Question about Looping - Add another cell value to itself, then print on its own cell, then LOOP for rest of the table

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am really new at VBA and I would appreciate it if anyone could help me with this scenario.

I need for a cell to add the value of another cell + the value of its own cell and print it on its own cell. After that I want it to loop over to the next cell.

*Example: Cell C2 + Cell C5 = Result printed on C2
THEN IT LOOPS AND DOES THE SAME FOR D2: Cell D2 + CELL D5 = Result printed on D2, and so on...*

I have managed to make the cells add another value to itself as below:

```
Sub LoopSelfAddingCell()

Dim sht3 as Worksheet

Set sht3 = Sheets("Test")
d = sht3.Range("C2").Value
d1 = sht3.Range("D2").Value

sht3.Range("C2") = d + Range("C5").Value
sht3.Range("D2") = d1 + Range("D5").Value

End Sub
```

As you can see, if I have a big table, it would be a lot of additional lines for each cell. In my case it is not impossible to do, but it would be quite annoying, more than anything, I just started learning, so I would like to learn about other options, so my question is if anyone knows of a more efficient way of doing this.

FYI. The solution doesn't necessarily needs to be "looping", it can be anything else, it would be interesting to see what other options are out there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the problem, you want to add the value from the yellow cell in each column to the value in the green cell in the same column and write the result in the green cell.

[image]

You can do this easily with VBA, a spreadsheet formula, or with Power Query. The spreadsheet formula is easiest.

## **Spreadsheet formula**

My test data are in Sheet2!A1:J7, as shown above.

```
=LET(
    d, A1:J7,
    newRow, CHOOSEROWS(d, 2) + CHOOSEROWS(d, 5),
    VSTACK(TAKE(d, 1), newRow, DROP(d, 2))
)
```

[image]

This works as follows:

1. assign the data range to the name d
2. calculate the newRow as the sum of row 2 and 5
3. return the header row, the new row, and the rows after row 2

## **Power Query**

You can do this somewhat easily with Power Query. You can copy this query text into a blank query, change the name of the table on the 'Source' line, and that should do the trick.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    
    /*
    Iterate through each column in the table, then 
    add the first data row (spreadsheet row 2 = table row index 0) to the 
    4th data row (spreadsheet row 5 = table row index 3)
    */
    NewRowValues = List.Transform(
        Table.ToColumns(Source),
        each _{0} + _{3}
    ),

    NewRow = Record.FromList(NewRowValues, Table.ColumnNames(Source)),

    /* Replace the first data row (spreadsheet row 2 = table index 0) with the new row */
    Result = Table.ReplaceRows(Source,0,1,{NewRow})
in
    Result
```

[image]

## **VBA**

```
Public Sub ReplaceSecondRow()


Dim dataRange As Range
Dim col As Integer
Dim oldValue As Variant
Dim newValue As Variant

Set dataRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:J7")

For col = 1 To dataRange.Columns.Count

    oldValue = dataRange.Cells(2, col)
    newValue = oldValue + dataRange.Cells(5, col)
    dataRange.Cells(2, col) = newValue
    
    Debug.Print "Replaced " & oldValue & " with " & newValue & " in column " & col

Next col


End Sub
```

For brevity, you can also just use this:

```
Public Sub ReplaceSecondRow()

Dim dataRange As Range
Dim col As Integer

Set dataRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:J7")

For col = 1 To dataRange.Columns.Count
    dataRange.Cells(2, col) = dataRange.Cells(2, col) + dataRange.Cells(5, col)
Next col

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the very well detailed explanation you gave. The best option for my workbook (and my limited knowledge) seems to be the VBA, second code you wrote to be exact ("For brevity, you can also just use this:")

There is only one issue, if I run the code once, it seems to run fine.  However, once I run it again, the macro basically deletes "green cells" and then adds the value from the "yellow cells". What I would need is for the green values to stay, and add the NEW yellow values onto that EXISTING green values. Do you think it is possible?

Comment: @EricAhn
As an example - in Col1 in my image. You run the macro once, and cell A2 will be 49. Now suppose we change cell A5 to 35 instead of 29. What value do you want to see in cell A2 when you run the macro again?

Comment: When I put in your code into the worksheet I am actually using, I had to make rearrangements to match the cells I actually need to apply these rules, I think I missunderstood something because when I do it on your example without changing any values in the code itself, it works like a charm.

I will try to figure it out. 
Thank you very much, you were of great help!